# Html5 CSS Table border not visible in IE 11

Tags: html, css

Earlier The Table showed borders. Then I added a property to my container
 text-align:center; 
The table did not move to center so I added
 display:inline-block; to the table.
That moved the table to the center and it looked good in Chrome and Firefox but it is not looking well in IE 11
The Table borders are missing.

```
table{
    margin:2px;
    width:200px;
    padding:4px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

I tried Google search and tried to set the zoom of IE 11

```
table{
    margin:2px;
    width:200px;
    padding:4px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This is how my table looks in IE 11

[image]

Comment: An alternate for centering would margin: 0 auto; be if you specify a width

Comment: I have not specified the width of my container if that is what you are talking about. My container looks like this                                                                             .container{
 margin:10px;
 padding:5px;
 border:2px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-color:black;
 border-radius:3px;
 text-align:center;
}

Comment: The width of element you want to center. U did this, i only mentioned it.

Comment: As we can't debug an image, provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `display:inline-block;` first and add margin. It should help

```
table {
 /* Remove this: margin:2px; */
 width:200px;
 padding:4px;
 margin: 2px auto;
}
```

Or check the link
https://www.granneman.com/webdev/coding/css/centertables

Comment: Yes That worked! Thank you so much.                                                                         table{
 
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:200px;
 padding:4px;
 
}

Answer (score -1):

Try to add in to your html code border = "1"

```
<table border = "1"></table>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_border.asp